# Embedable Youtube 360 API to know which direction on the transverse plane they're looking at?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api, 360-degrees

I would like to embed a youtube video on a webapp but have my own controls, from what I understand, I can use [the iframe API](http://ttps://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for everything (how far in the video, stop, start, etc.), but I can't seem to find anything on 360-specific elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube 360 videos are not fully supported in Youtube API as of the moment. It is currently filed as a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7547&q=reporter%3Asmartsystemdesign&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary).